# Jaspersoft MongoDB Query Language: Aggregation and projection

Tags: mongodb, server, jasper-reports

I have a Mongo Query which is extracting the subducument from a collection and projects its fields.
The query is working fine, but I am not able to put it into the Jaspersoft MongoDB Query which is necessary for getting the dataset!
            I looked through https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-mongodb-query-language but without success.
            Is anybody able to convert this statement into a working query for a jasper report?

```
   **db.getCollection('a').aggregate({
            $unwind: "$b"
        }, {
            $project: {
                attribute: "$b.attribute"
            }
        })**



        Any help would be highly appreciated!
```